# display text retrieved from ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

I have the following javascript that set the datafield to be displayed in the html page. There is a variable called "page_content" and the data stored in it looks like `"<p>return product</p>"`.

When I try to echo it out in the html page, it shows `"<p>return product</p>"` instead of `"return product"`. How can I go about doing it?

Code for the javascript

```
(function () {

    var apppage = angular.module("apppage", ['dx']);
    apppage.controller('pageControl', function ($scope) {

        var column = [
            {
                dataField: "page_content",
                caption: "Content",
                selectedFilterOperation: 'contains',
                allowGrouping: true
            },
            {
                dataField: "nothing",
                caption: "",
                allowFiltering: false,
                allowSorting: false,
                cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
                    //var newHref = baseUrl + "backendCategory/edit_product?item_id=" + options.key.item_id;
                    var editHref = baseUrl + "backendPage/edit_page?page_id=" + options.key.page_id;
                    var deleteHref = baseUrl + "backendPage/edit_page?page_id=" + options.key.page_id;
                    $('<div class="btn-group" style="min-width:150px">'
                            + '<a class="btn btn-default" href=' + editHref + '><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>'
                            //+ '<a class="btn btn-default" href=' + newHref + 'alt="Copy"><i class="icon-copy"></i></a>'
                            + '<a class="btn btn-danger" href=' + deleteHref + 'onclick="return areyousure();" alt="Delete"><i class="icon-times "></i></a>'
                            + '</div>').appendTo(container)
                }
            }
        ];
        $scope.dataGridOptions = {
            dataSource: page_list,
            paging: {
                pageSize: 10,
                pageIndex: 1
            },
            headerFilter:{
                visible:true
            },
            searchPanel: {
                visible: true,
                width: 240,
                placeholder: "Search..."
            },
            columns: column
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

CK Editor returns the HTML, by onverting the formatted text inside the ditor to valid HTML. If you just want the text, why are you using an editor and why  not a simple textarea?

If you want the text to not HTML, you could use a HTML to Markdown converter. But it wont be just plain text. If you want plain text, use textarea, rather than CKEditor.

[HTML To Markdown.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi55Kjp8sbKAhUWkY4KHb8HDTEQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdomchristie.github.io%2Fto-markdown%2F&usg=AFQjCNHCRgm5pxQxGfMawVZx-Rd-tdF2rA&sig2=vxfKJ6npujyzOvJ0K8Lgww&bvm=bv.112454388,d.c2E)